# Jsoup need to get data-href not a[href]

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

im trying to extract links from a webpage code 
if i use href i can put links that look like this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosco_(TV_series)&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiL4seHxKfLAhVCZw8KHXwpBqkQFggTMAA&usg=AFQjCNHYnnqiz2AzLDDFhcxTWNvpRMzwfQ

if you run this link its dead . 
this is the correct link.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosco_(TV_series) 
while looking at the (html)code i noticed there was a "data-href ="
which contained the correct link how do i use jsoup to get the data-href link ?

Comment: Please provide example of html code you want to parse, explain which part you want to extract and describe problem you are facing while writing your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question needs improvement. Start here to find out how questions should be formulated: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just get it via `Element.attr(name)`?

```
String template ="<div data-href=\"https://example.com/some/path\">";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(template);
Element el = doc.select("div").first();

System.out.println(el.attr("data-href"));
```

Comment: yeah thats what i have so far except when i try looking for data-href instead of href i get a blank return

Comment: I would suggest that you provide the HTML and prepare a failing example together with what you expect to read.

Comment: i feed google a string to search and grabbed the html returned by google ?

Comment: Sorry, that does not help. If you expect people to respond with meaningful answers you need to give them the info they need. For me at least it is utterly unclear what your problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to get links from a google search.when I send google the search string I grab the html code from the results page using a [href] I can find links like the first one. When I inspected the html I found the data-href with the correct link but I can't get my program to find data -href in the html